How to update first layer weights in a neural network?
I’m trying to make a neural network without using any deep learning library that recognizes numbers in the mnist database. Its structure is: 784 input neurons, 10 hidden neurons (only 1 hidden layer) and 10 output neurons.
There’s 10 biases for the hidden layer.
I think I know how to update the last layer weights, but not the first ones as the last layer’s weights influence the result. I dont know how to update biases neither. If I made any mistake in the last layer update, please let me know.
Here’s the code:
#forward propagation
def forward(inp, w1, w2, biases):
    hidsRes = []
    outRes = []

    for i in range(len(w1)):
        n = np.dot(inp, w1[i])

        n += biases[i]
        n = relu(n)

        hidsRes.append(n)

    for i in range(len(w2)):
        n = np.dot(hidsRes, w2[i])

        outRes.append(n)

    return softmax(outRes)

#backpropagation
def back(avgResult, w1, w2, lr):
    for i, w in enumerate(w2):
        w2[i] += lr * avgResult[i] #I only update the last layer based on the average error of each neuron

def train(inps, hids, outs, randomWeightDiff, batchs, gens, lr):
    w1, w2, b = initNn(inps, hids, outs, randomWeightDiff)

    #loading the mnist dataset
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = getData()

    for gen in range(gens):
        errors = []

        x_train, y_train = shuffle(x_train, y_train)
        
        for batch in range(batchs):  
            prediction = forward(tolist(x_train[batch].tolist()), w1, w2, b)
            y = y_train[batch]

            target = [0 if i != y else 1 for i in range(10)]

            errors.append([prediction[i] - target[i] for i in range(10)])

        print(errors)

        avg = [sum([errors[i][j] for j in range(len(errors))]) / 10 for i in range(10)]

        back(avg, w1, w2, lr)
        print("Generation {gen} \n" + f"{avg}")

train(784, 10, 10, 2, 100, 1000, 0.01)

I tried simulating a lot of neural networks and mutating the best ones, but it was too slow and it was not working.

maybe ask on similar portals DataScience and CrossValidated. OR on forum on portal Kaggle

you may also try to read source code in MachineLearning-From-Scratch

I'm not sure but first you have to calculate average error and later you have to use derivatives to update layers. Not use only average error to update last layer.

I tried to find some example code - and I found only How to Code a Neural Network with Backpropagation In Python (from scratch) - MachineLearningMastery.com. And python - numpy : calculate the derivative of the softmax function - Stack Overflow

After doing some research, I think I found how to find the gradient of a weight[L][i]: gradient_of_weight[L][i] = loss_function_derivative(a[L])[i] * activation_function_derivative(pre_activation[L-1])[i] * activation[L-1][i]. Activation_function_derivative is the derivative of the activation function of layer L. Is this correct?

frankly, I don't know. I was trying to learn it (and code from scratch) long time ago so I don't remember details. Today I only use tensorflow or keras
